# Determine Subtype of a Base type to display different properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC View that also calls some partial views/

There is a Document which can be of varying types, for instance a Purchase Order or an Invoice. Each of the different document types has some unique fields that the other doesn't have. They all have some properties from the base "Document" class.

My view needs to display the document details depending on the specific type of document, but then continue and show the common elements that all document types have.

I want to pass the document through as a Document so I don't have to duplicate code, and then when it comes to displaying the unique aspects of the document, just detect which subtype the document is, and use a switch statement to display a particular partial view for that type.

However, it seems that if I pull up the Document from the Documents dbset, it will not be detected as a Purchase Order or Invoice, and cannot be cast to the subtype.

How do I accomplish this?

Take a Document -> Determine which type it is -> Display Unique Details in a partial View -> Display Generic Details in partial View.

So this way the code that handles the common aspects can be reused.

Some Code for context:
Main Controller:

```
public ActionResult Main(string doctype, int id)
    {
        ActionCenterViewModel acvm = new ActionCenterViewModel();
        acvm.Document = db.Documents
            .Where(i => i.ID == id)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    return View(acvm);
}
```

Main View:

```
@model Production.ViewModels.ActionCenterViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Main";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/actioncenter.css")" />
@Html.Action("DisplayDocumentDetails", Model.Document)
```

Secondary Action:

```
public ActionResult DisplayDocumentDetails(Document doc)
    {
        switch (doc.DocumentType)
        {
            case "WorkOrder":
                return View("_DisplayWorkOrderDetails");
        }
                return null;

    }
```

Secondary View:

```
@model Production.Models.WorkOrder

<div id="documentDetails">
<div class="actionCenterDocInfoLabel fLeft">WorkOrder:</div> 
<div class="actionCenterDocInfoValue fLeft"> @Model.ID</div>

<div class="actionCenterDocInfoLabel fLeft leftMargin20">Vendor:</div> 
<div class="actionCenterDocInfoValue fLeft"> @Model.Vendor.FriendlyName</div>
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this is you have an inheritance structure, and you're passing the base type to the *main* view.  From this *main* view you are rendering the common fields.  If the actual model type is a derived class, you can do a check within your *main* view and call `Html.RenderPartial`.

For example:

```
@if (Model is MyDerivedType) {
    Html.RenderPartial("myPartial", (MyDerivedType)Model);
}
```

Where the `myPartial` view accepts a model of type `MyDerivedType`.  My example is probably borked, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I'm actually dpong an Html.Action and I am using a switch in the controller! But I "Cannot cast 'doc' (which has an actual type of 'Production.Models.Document') to 'Production.Models.WorkOrder'"

Comment: How are `Document` and `WorkOrder` related?

Comment: Document is the Base Class of WorkOrder. So WorkOrder derives from Document. There are going to be other types of documents such as invoice that will need to use the same page.

Comment: The Main controller seems to know that the Document is a WorkOrder, even though I pulled it from db.Documents. BUt when it passes through the view and then into the DocumentDetails controller it loses that, and doesn't let me cast

Comment: Are you using a strongly typed view?

Comment: Yes the second view is strongly typed to WorkOrder

Comment: If the first (full) view is strongly typed to `Document`, and the second (partial) view is strongly typed to `WorkOrder`, the code I pasted should work.

Comment: The full view uses a View model of which one of the properties is the Document, strongly typed. But the controller which calls the secondary view is strongly typed to Document, and that seems to be the point where it stops being a dynamic proxy workorder and becomes a straitlaced Document.

Comment: If in your view, if you call `@Model.GetType().ToString()` it should say `bla.bla.bla.WorkOrder` if you're passing a work order to the outer view even though it's strongly typed to `Document`.

Comment: I posted some code to help out here. Even though I pull from db.Documents, as a document, the compiler treats it as a WorkOrder up until the secondary action.

Comment: In your example, you need to pass the `doc` to the call to `View` in your `ActionResult`.

Comment: My problem is that in the line of switch(doc.DocumentType), it doesn't detect that it is a workorder.

Comment: Is a view not able to pass a dynamic proxy to a controller? Is something happening because the object is being passed Controller -> View -> Back to Controller? Should I just pass the ID and query EF again? I was trying to avoid the extra DB call